# StopIteration in Python

Tags: python, exception, generator, stopiteration

I encounter a problem while reading functional programming python.

```
def get_log_lines(log_file): 
    line = read_line(log_file) 
    while True:
        try:
            if complex_condition(line):
                yield line
            line = read_line(log_file)
        except StopIteration:
            raise
```

A `try...except` statement is added to surround the `read_line`. Why not just let `read_line` throw the `StopIteration` exception like this:

```
def get_log_lines(log_file): 
    line = read_line(log_file) 
    while True:
        if complex_condition(line):
            yield line
        line = read_line(log_file)
```

Comment: Indeed, the `try..except` can safely be removed. It is pointless here.

Comment: Seems to be useless here, but you should specify what exactly read_line does or how it will behave when the iterator is exhausted.

Comment: @dorvak: This is from the free O'Reilly ebook [*Functional programming in Python*](http://www.oreilly.com/programming/free/functional-programming-python.csp), and David does not share the implementation in that book. Even worse, between different examples, it switches from an iterator to a `next()`-like function, two very different implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is *any* reason to keep the `try...except` there. The re-raise will still carry the same traceback, for example, so the behaviour of the generator is unchanged with it there.

In other words, it is pointless there, perhaps a left-over artefact of a refactoring.

You can simplify the loop even further, removing the redundant first line:

```
def get_log_lines(log_file): 
    while True:
        line = read_line(log_file) 
        if complex_condition(line):
            yield line
```

Answer (score 0):

The author was writing an example.  While the try...catch block doesn't actually do anything here, he probably included it so that you could SEE how the loop would get broken.